# Location on nant build file in Visual Studio solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nant

I am just starting to use Nant and have a quick question -

When using Nant with a ASP.NET web application, where is the recommended place to put the build file?  Should it be part of the web project or should it be just directly under the solution?  Am I over thinking this?

Comment: What's the benefit of learning NAnt instead of MSBuild in 2017?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to place your build file along with the whole project. You also should create a separate directory for this build file (e.g. named Build), because in future you will have to create one more build (or .include) file and one more and then you will have a set of build files that should be grouped.